# Center Alignment in Android

Tags: android, alignment, android-linearlayout

I want to know how to center a GUI widget programmatically.
Kindly help me. I am using a LinearLayout.

Many Regards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most of the time, you don't have to do this if you defined `android:gravity="center"` in the layout file.

You can also perform this by getting the screen size then doing some calculations on it, but this is not recommended.

Comment: Use getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); This will give you screen details so you can perform you calculation using this data.

Answer (score 10):

You need to set gravity for a view as [CENTER_HORIZONTAL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html#CENTER_HORIZONTAL)

with the markup you should use:

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
```

The difference between `android:gravity` and `android:layout_gravity` is that `android:gravity` positions the contents of that view (i.e. what’s inside the view), whereas `android:layout_gravity` positions the view with respect to its parent

In the code you should use:

```
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Comment: With which method can I use the CENTER_HORIZONTAL. I want to align an ImageButton at center from my Java code.

Comment: But ImageButton have no setGravity() method.

Comment: android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" could be write android:layout_gravity="center"